# Laravel load login view instead of redirecting to /login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, php-7

I have a Laravel application with following routes:

1. http://site-name/ (auth)
2. http://site-name/home (public)
3. http://site-name/about (public)

As http://site-name/ needs authorized user, it needs a login check.
I have written a following route for this

`Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');`

Where SiteController is,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('play');
    }
}
```

Above `__construct()` will redirect the user to http://site-name/login view.

Now, the tricky part starts. I need to modify my laravel application such that, for login, it would show the login view to unauthorized user on http://site-name/ instead of redirecting to http://site-name/login for login.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your unauthorized user redirect path. Go to the :

> app\Exceptions\Handler.php

inside the `unauthenticated` method you can change your redirect path on`http://site-name/` instead of `http://site-name/login` this.

```
 protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('/login');  // Here you should be specify your unauthorized redirect url path.
    }
```

Comment: RimonKhan ,I wish to load login view instead of redirecting to some new url or route to show the login view.

Comment: you just replace this url `return redirect()->guest('/login');` what you want like `return redirect()->guest('/');`

Comment: Currently in Laravel-5.3, [Authenticate.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7804a8eb3a2944157ee3d154fa81335cddbb5156/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php) have some different implementation. It does not seem to like mentioned in above code.

How do I handle?

Comment: Thanks. Yes unauth exception is handled there. But I am looking for a solution where I don't have to redirect to any other url. But the login view should be loaded in the same page where authorization is required.

Comment: if your problem solved. make sure mark the current answer. Thank You

Comment: I don't wish to redirect the user to any other url. But, to show the login view on the same url where authorization is requried.

Answer (score 0):

as you asked in the comment section, here is a way to not redirect, instead just render a Template!

But I think you want to stay on the same page and show an error or something ?
Check out this link:
[Laracasts Ajax call login Laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-login-with-ajax-form)

If you render a view be sure it's a web route and not an api route.
If it's an api route be sure to deactivate throttling in

> app/Http/Kernel.php

Example of Rendering a template on unauthenticated():

> app\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
/**
 * @param                         $request
 * @param AuthenticationException $exception
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return \View::make('login',['title' => 'unauthenticated']);
}
```